# How 2 compare lines from a file with a string

Tags: python

I recently began to develop a project for my GitHub page as I am learning python programing language so I am trying to Create a Student DBMS program in which there are multiple functions as One of them is explained below:

In this Function, I am trying to read data from the file in which only usernames and password are stored and after that, I am getting the user input (USERNAME AND PASSWORD) and storing them in the form of string using this method --> `string = 'user = ' + user + ',' + 'pass = ' + password` (as the USERNAMES AND PASSWORDS stored in the file looks like this   --> user = %username%, pass = %password% ) after this when I am trying to compare both the string it doesn't show any output. **Full Working Steps are Given Below**

```
>>> user = 'admin'
>>> password = 'password'
>>> string = 'user = ' + user + ',' + 'pass = ' + password
>>> print(string)
user = admin, pass = password
>>> type(string)
<class 'str'>
>>> import os
>>> os.chdir('C:\\Users\\alexm\\Desktop\\Python Practice')
>>> file = open('aman.txt','r')
>>> for line in file:
        print(line)


user = admin, pass = password

user = adminn, pass = pass
>>> for line in file:
        type(line)
        print(line)


>>> for line in file:
        type(line)
        print(line)
```

**NOTE: THE ABOVE LINES ARE DIRECTLY TAKEN FROM THE PYTHON SHELL**

Am I doing this one right or I am wrong(IF yes then please Help ME)

Comment: You can only read through the file once, either that or execute `file.seek(0)` before iterarating again with the for loop.

Comment: I don't see any comparison in your code...

Comment: don´t use `pass` as a variable name, it's a reserved python keyword.

Comment: @jmunsch already told you why it does not work - and I hope you know that it is not a good idea to store passwords this way ;)

Comment: Store your data in a computer-readable format like JSON. Inventing your own format wild create more work and murky corner cases (your current design has ambiguities in how to represent and handle values containing whitespace, comma, or an equals sign).

Comment: Sorry because I forgot to add comparison statement in the question above and I dont know how to work on JSON as i am new to these I have recentl switched from c++ to Python

Comment: @AlexMercer You can find plenty of resources on JSON, and the `json` module is rather straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried doing:

```
If line == string:
    print('they are the same!')
else:
    print(f'{string} is not the same as {line}')
```

By the way, I would recommend change the variable name `string` to `user_input` or something like that.

Comment: That means the strings are not the same. Check my code, I added an else so you always get an output.

Comment: I did actually tried your code and it made my computer skills in trouble it is showing output like this one  `user = admin, pass = password is not the same as user = admin, pass = password`

Comment: Then clearly your strings are not the same. Make sure you don't have trailing spaces or extra spaces in between.